# beeline spark thrift server issue

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveserver2

I was trying to access spark sql through jdbc but facing some error. I am trying to run beeline

```
! /usr/lib/spark/bin/beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://host:10016/default;transportMode=binary'  -e '' 2>&1| awk '{print}'|grep -i -e 'Connection refused' -e 'Invalid URL' -e 'Error: Could not open'
```

`host` value is correct in command.(deliberately written for making it generic)

```
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: host:10016/default;transportMode=binary: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)
```

hive.server2.thrift.port=10016 and mode is binary.
I verified the process is running on this port.
I checked the spark thrift server logs:

**link to logs** : https://pastebin.com/G5Mwaw7E

It says

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
(pasted the logs in above link).
```

I am using spark version 3.1.0 , hive 3.1.2 and hadoop 3.1.2.
Following this guide
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html#interacting-with-different-versions-of-hive-metastore

I set "spark.sql.hive.metastore.version" to 3.1.2 and set jars to point to hivemetastore 3.1.2 jars but still getting the same error.

From logs I also got suspicious about a mismatch in the version of datanucleus core in hive and spark but both use the same version.
https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-3.1/pom.xml#L129
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.1/pom.xml#L184 (edited)

```
21/05/14 13:42:44 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName unknown - will be ignored
21/05/14 13:42:44 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL unknown - will be ignored
21/05/14 13:42:44 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName unknown - will be ignored
21/05/14 13:42:44 INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
21/05/14 13:42:44 INFO Persistence: Property spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword unknown - will be ignored
21/05/14 13:42:44 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
21/05/14 13:42:45 WARN Datastore: Error initialising derby schema : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NAME 'org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.DerbySQLFunction.ascii' CALLED ON NULL' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NAME 'org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.DerbySQLFunction.ascii' CALLED ON NULL' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
```

^ this looks suspecious too, metastore is mysql 
Is this a known issue , how should this be fixed. Let me know if anything else is required.
Thanks

Comment: Without revealing any info that you may not wish to reveal... Is the hostname of your Hive host literally `host` (as in `jdbc:hive2://host:10016/default`)? Or is that just a deliberate placeholder for this question?

Comment: no, hostname is correct xyz.com, It was too long so i just shortened it and made it generic. @andrewjames

Comment: is this a kerberized hadoop/ hive installation?

Comment: no, it is not kerberized.added some suspicious logs in question.